# Volume level on button in flash

Tags: flash, animation, audio, actionscript-2, timeline

i want to control sound in my movie clip by the button which i designed in flash. for ex.: my default sound is 100% on home button & when i click on contact(last button) the volume level goes to 20% same as in between buttons.

i use this script to call the sound in flash

bgSound = new Sound(this);
bgSound.attachSound("sound1");
bgSound.start(0,99);

now tell me what i put in buttons to manage sound level.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume your using AS2 based on the method calls shown, also based on that assumption did a quick google search and came back with this:

```
    bgSound.setVolume(20);
```

http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/49/1/Volume-Slider-attachSound-method/Page1.html

If you are using another version of the language and I'm wrong here please let me know and I'll try to correct.

Comment: I already used this but i want when i click on button then the volume level goes down like. i have five button home,about,service,profile,contact. now when i click on contact button the volume level goes 20%, on profile 40%, service60%, about80% & at home 100%..

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand what the problem is, are you saying that regardless of what button you press it always lowers the volume?

Comment: yes i want the lower volume when i click on button & if you dont understand please give me your mail id i'll send the file then u understand. Thanks

Comment: HEY IF ANY BODY HAVE THE SOLUTION FOR THIS PLEASE LET ME KNOW ITS URGENT.. PLEASE..

Comment: Sorry still just don't get exactly what's wrong you say you're trying to get it to lower the volume when you click the buttons, and when you click the buttons it lowers the volume so what is the problem?  is it related to this: http://www.ultrashock.com/forum/viewthread/21856/ that the sounds are tied to the same MovieClip and adjusting the volume of one affects the others

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it ( i hope ) , here you are 
I will go from ground zero

Download as2 version of TweenMax
http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

Put com folder in same folder with ur project fla file

use this at top of your first frame which include rest of your code

```
import com.greensock.*;
```

Use this code to tween between target volumes

```
TweenMax.fromTo(bgSound,1,{volume:bgSound.getVolume},{volume:TARGETVOLUME)});
```

TARGETVOLUME is number between 0-100 in actionscript 2
for example 
if you want to change sound to 60 when u go to services 
put this in ur onRelease

```
TweenMax.fromTo(bgSound,1,{volume:bgSound.getVolume},{volume:60)});
```

And remember if u include actions on buttons ( which as2 allow )
target objects truly

If u can't tell me to provide a sample for u ;) 
Also u can do it with out tweenmax with events like enterframe but tweenmax is awsome hope u get to it and use it for many other features which save u a lot of time